# Como suspender um comando sem atrapalhar comandos que estejam ativos

Tags: python, python-3.x, time

bom queria saber se conheçem um comando em python que suspenda o funcionamento de um comando(por alguns segundos)sem atrapalhar os outros comandos que estejam ativos, pois estava querendo fazer um sistema de aluguel mas o time.sleep() não deixava os outros comandos funcionarem.
aqui um exemplo:

```
import time
aluguel=False
dinheiro=0
while True:
    time.sleep(10)
    aluguel=True
    dinheiro=dinheiro-1
    #o time.sleep inpede o funcionamento do codigo a seguir mas n quero que isso aconteça
a=str(input(''))
if a == MONEY:
    dinheiro=dinheiro+1'
```

Comment: fiz uma alteração explicando melhor

Comment: O que **exatamente** este código deveria fazer? Pode explicá-lo com palavras?

Comment: de segundos em segundos o programa vai cobrar o aluguel e vc vai ter q fazer dinheiro para não ser despejado, tentei usar o time.sleep() mas ele para o programa inteiro, eu so quero fazer uma contagem que não interfira em nada

Comment: Tem conhecimento sobre Threads?

Comment: não sou meio que iniciante;--;

Comment: O que quer dizer esse *MONEY* ? Para que ele serve?

Comment: fiz o codigo sem testar pra dar como exemplo._.Esqueçi de colocar as aspas, esse e o codigo pra fazer dinheiro

Comment: No meu modesto conhecimento, vejo as soluções utilizando *threads* ou *asyncio*. Ambas são relativamente complexas para quem está começando. Por quê precisa fazer isso?

Comment: Por que eu quero ._.

Comment: Então comece lendo sobre paralelismo e concorrência. Sem entender os conceitos, ao meu ver, não adiantará ter uma resposta com um código que funciona. Estude o que são *threads*, processos, como elas são gerenciadas pelo processador, como trabalhar com questões de concorrência, etc.

Comment: Isso daqui me parece muito ser um [**problema XY**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/132).

Answer (score 1):

Então - programas "normais", nesse nível de aprendizado sempre são executados com uma instrução após outra.

Se você deseja que uma parte do seu código faça uma coisa, enquanto outra parte do seu código faz outra, você precisa ter "alguma coisa" que controle qual parte do programa vai ser executada, e como o processamento vai passar para outra parte enquanto a primeira é "pausada".

A primeira coisa que vem a cabeça de todo mundo quando você menciona isso é o conceito de "threads". Uma "thread" é como se fosse um programa separado, rodando no mesmo código, e nas mesmas variáveis. Você *poderia* ter uma thread rodando código de uma função, enquanto que outra thread roda código em outra função. Nesse caso o `time.sleep` teria o efeito que você espera na questão: aquela thread para,e a outra continua sua execução.

No entanto threads estão longe de serem didáticas: a pessoa tem que realmente ter noção do fluxo do programa e várias outras coisas para fazer algo com threads direto dar certo.

No seu código, podemos ver que você não usa funções. Se você não dominou ainda o uso de funções até o ponto de serem algo trivial, não tem mesmo nenhuma alternativa - por que até para pensar nessa "pausa" fica complicado.  Pra onde o programa "vai" se parte do código está "pausada". Pra onde ele "volta"? Além de tudo o que é descrito para elas, funções servem como unidades de organização do código para "saber" qual parte está em execução. (Para criar uma thread, por exemplo, você passa uma função como parâmetro, como ponto de inicio do "programa secundário" daquela thread).

Então vá, e aprenda sobre funções,e como as variáveis *dentro* de uma função são "estanques" - não são visíveis ou alteráveis fora da função, e como você pode ter variáveis "globais" que são compartilhadas.

Depois disso você vai conseguir pensar de forma organizada em partes do código que executam em paralelo.

Daí vem o motivo de eu estar escrevendo essa resposta. Como eu coloquei acima, tem que existir "alguma coisa" que gerencia qual parte do seu código está executando em paralelo. Mas essa coisa não precisa ser necessariamente seu próprio código controlando threads. A biblioteca para interfaces gráficas que vem com o Python - tkinter, pode fazer isso muito bem, cuidando de toda a complexidade para você.

Quando você usa uma biblioteca gráfica, em geral seu programa declara todas as funções, classes e objetos que vai usar, e transfere o controle do programa para a biblioteca. No caso do tkinter, você chama a função `mainloop`, e isso tipicamente é a última linha do seu programa. A partir daí, o controle passa para a biblioteca gráfica, que vai chamar funções e métodos do *seu* código, que você configurou nas linhas acima. Por exemplo, ele pode chamar uma função que altera a vairável global "saldo"  quando o usuário clicar um botão, ou depois de passar um certo intervalo de tempo, por exemplo.

O processo seria o mesmo com outras bibliotecas gráficas, como gtk+ e Qt - o que elas tem em comum é que gerenciam a parte de "qual código roda quando", que para os usuários é o "comum", já que crescemos com aplicativos que tem menus prontos para serem usados, ou formulários web. E mais importante ainda: sempre, sempre organizar seu código em funções, antes de mais nada!

Aqui segue um exemplo que fica parecido com o que você estava tentando, usando o framework "tkinter":

```
import tkinter


def adiciona(*args):
    saldo.set(saldo.get()  + int(valor.get()))
    mostra_saldo()

def mostra_saldo(*args):
    mensagem["text"] = ("Saldo atual: {}".format(saldo.get()))

def cobra_aluguel():
    saldo.set(int(saldo.get()) - 1)
    mostra_saldo()
    janela.after(2000, cobra_aluguel)

def constroi():
    # Essas variáveis globais estarão visíveis em todas as funções.
    global janela, mensagem, saldo, valor
    # como as outras funções não modificam as mesmas com o sinal de "=",
    # apenas chamando métodos, não precisam declara-las como globais também. 

    janela = tkinter.Tk()
    valor = tkinter.Variable()
    saldo = tkinter.Variable()
    mensagem = tkinter.Label(janela)
    texto = tkinter.Label(janela, text="Valor a receber:")
    entrada = tkinter.Entry(janela, textvariable=valor)
    # O parametro "command" indica a função chamada quando o botão 
    # for clicado:
    botao = tkinter.Button(janela, text="Adicionar", command=adiciona)

    # métodos para exibir controles na janela, da forma mais simples:
    # um abaixo do outro:
    mensagem.pack()
    texto.pack()
    entrada.pack()
    botao.pack()
    # Exbibe o saldo inicial
    saldo.set(0)
    mostra_saldo()
    # Cobra aluguel daqui 2000 milisegundos: 
    janela.after(2000, cobra_aluguel)

    # Transfere o controle do programa para o tkinter,
    # que vai chamar "cobra_aluguel" no intervalo de tempo 
    # e "adiciona"  quando o botao for pressionado
    tkinter.mainloop()

constroi()
```